# XML Dynamic Object and IEnumberables

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, dynamic, expandoobject

I am having some issues with my DynamicXML object, it is parsing XML great, and for single elements works great, but when I have multiple children elements its falling over.
I am obviously missing something, but I dont know what.

Here is the class:

```
public class DynamicXml : DynamicObject
{
    readonly XElement element;

    public DynamicXml(string xml)
    {
        element = XElement.Parse(xml);
    }

    public DynamicXml(XElement xElement)
    {
        element = xElement;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (element == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }

        var sub = element.Element(binder.Name);

        if (sub == null)
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            result = new DynamicXml(sub);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return element != null ? element.Value : string.Empty;
    }

    public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        try
        {
            result = Convert.ChangeType(element.Value, binder.ReturnType);
            return true;
        }
        catch { }

        return base.TryConvert(binder, out result);
    }
}
```

This is how I would use it

```
var response = "<response><foo>some xml here</foo></response>"
result = new DynamicXml(response);

var newObj = new SumObject();
newObj.Foo = result.foo;
```

Now this works fine, but if my xml were:

```
<response>
   <foo>
     <bahs>
        <bah>value here</bah>
        <bah>value here</bah>
        <bah>value here</bah>
     </bahs>
   </foo>
<response>
```

I would want to use some thing like:

```
for(var bahs in result.foo.bahs)
{
   //magic code here
}
```

but this isnt what is happening I just get an error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'DynamicXml' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution,  I needed to implement IEnumerable and GetEnumerator()

here is the solution class:

```
    public class DynamicXml : DynamicObject, IEnumerable
    {
        readonly XElement element;

        public DynamicXml(string xml)
        {
            element = XElement.Parse(xml);
        }

        public DynamicXml(XElement xElement)
        {
            element = xElement;
        }

        public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            if (element == null)
            {
                result = null;
                return false;
            }

            var sub = element.Element(binder.Name);

            if (sub == null)
            {
                result = null;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                result = new DynamicXml(sub);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return element != null ? element.Value : string.Empty;
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return element.Elements().Select(child => new DynamicXml(child)).GetEnumerator();
        }

        public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            try
            {
                result = Convert.ChangeType(element.Value, binder.ReturnType);
                return true;
            }
            catch { }

            return base.TryConvert(binder, out result);
        }
    }
```